# Datetime in yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.fff format

Tags: apex

My webservice requires an input parameter of datetime of this format : yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.fff. I tried this:

```
Datetime myDT = Datetime.now(); 
String myDate = myDT.format('yyyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.fff');
```

says the format is not recognized. How do I create a date time in this format?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the format be `yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSS`? Capital M is for month and lower case is for minute. Also capital S is for milliseconds. The letters are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: `hh` will display the hours in 12 hour format and `HH` will display it in 24 hour format.  `HH` might be what you are looking to use if you are using this format to create a unique string.

Answer (score 4):

Your format template does not match the valid strings.

As BarCotter said, `yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSS` will work since it uses the formatting as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html